# Return sublists in increasing length order

Tags: sorting, haskell

I am trying to create a Haskell function that takes a list of sublists as its argument and returns these sublists in order of increasing length. I have this but I am now stuck

```
increasing :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
increasing xs = sublist [] xs where
sublist a [b] = [ a ++ [b] ]
sublist a (b:bs) = [ a ++ [b] ] ++ sublist (a ++ [b]) bs

increasingTest = [
  increasing ["Ever", "wondered", "how", "many", "dinosaurs", "ever", 
              "roamed", "the", "Earth"] ==
             ["how","the","Ever","many","ever",
              "Earth","roamed","wondered","dinosaurs"],
  increasing ["Precambrian", "Cambrian", "Ordovician", "Silurian"] == 
             ["Cambrian","Silurian","Ordovician","Precambrian"],
  increasing ["a", "1", "22", "bb"] == ["a","1","22","bb"]
  ]
```

Comment: Please stop adding irrelevant tags to your questions. This has nothing to do with lenses or the `stack` Haskell package management/build system.

Comment: Can you express this problem in terms of a *more general* idea? I don't know what `sublist` is supposed to do, but I'm pretty sure it's not going to help you solve this problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @dfeuer I've edited. the problem and testing example are now clear, though not the OP code. "sublists" = list's elements (which happen to be lists, themselves), AFAICT.

Comment: @WillNess, yes, I was able to figure it out from the examples. I was guiding the OP toward detailed description as a key problem-solving step.

Comment: @dfeuer personally, I can never follow a badly mis-formatted code until I put it in order, so doing _that_, for me, is the first step. :) BTW the definition can also be derived _by generalizing_ from the examples themselves, as long as they are proper.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right you want to sort just by the length?

If so then you can just use `sortOn` from `Data.List`:

```hs
import Data.List (sortOn)

increasing :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
increasing = sortOn length
```

`sortOn` will take a function `a -> b` where `b` is in `Ord` and then use this `Ord` instance to sort your list (ascending) - it's quite handy.

This will validate all your tests.

---

If you would want to sort first by length and then by *dictionary*  you can easily adapt this solution like this:

```hs
import Data.List (sortOn)

increasing :: Ord a => [[a]] -> [[a]]
increasing = sortOn (\xs -> (length xs, xs))
```

this works because there is a `Ord` instance for tuples (having all `Ord` components) that works by first comparing the first component of the tuple and if those are equal moving on to the next component.

Answer (score 0):

To follow your code's direction, you could try

```
increasing :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
increasing [] = []
increasing xs = shorterListsFirst [] xs 
  where
```

So if all that's left in `xs` is one element, it is by construction the longest, so just take it in:

```
  shorterListsFirst a [b] = a ++ [b]
```

And how do we achieve this correctness by construction? By *wishful thinking*, that's how:

```
  shorterListsFirst a (b:bs) 
      | shorterThanAll b bs = shorterListsFirst (a ++ [b]) bs
```

so if `b` is the shortest, we take it off, and keep it. And if not, we put it back, for later:

```
      | otherwise = shorterListsFirst a (bs ++ [b])
```

And that's that. All that's left is to implement the predicate we used, according to *how* we've used it:

```
-- shorterThanAll b bs ==> True or False
shorterThanAll  b []  = True
shorterThanAll  b [c] = shorter b c
shorterThanAll  b [c,d] = shorter b c && shorter b d
shorterThanAll  b [c,d,e] = (shorter b c && shorter b d) && shorter b e
.....
```

We'll need to implement this `shorter` predicate too later, but we've got bigger problems than that for now. We can't well keep enumerating all the cases for all the explicit lengths of the second argument -- where would we stop?

No fear, we can apply some equational reasoning and rearrange it as

```
                          = shorter b c && (shorter b d && shorter b e)
                          = shorter b c && (shorterThanAll b [d,e])
                                           ----------------------  !
```

And what's so special about lists of length 3? Or 2, or 1 for that matter -- they are all non-empty lists, having a "head" element, and a (possibly even empty) "tail". So we define instead:

```
shorterThanAll  b (c:de)  = shorter b c && (shorterThanAll b de)
```

I'll leave it to you to define the predicate `shorter`. There's one thing to watch out for. It shouldn't actually be "shorter", but "not longer", to avoid infinite looping.

After we've finished all this, your tests successfully pass.

Comment: I really think speedy generalization is the key. Your answer is not so easy to understand, even for be. Now it would be interesting to see how to solve this problem when some of the lists are much longer than others. It suggests "copying" the lists, and repeatedly dropping one element from the copy of each list. Then collect the full lists associated with each copy, and repeat.

Comment: @dfeuer strange, that, and totally unexpected :) because I wrote it with the mind of being the most accessible and approachable take on the problem for the OP, also following the general direction of their code. and it turns out to be opaque! I was focusing on correctness/finding _a_ solution, not at all thinking in terms of efficiency -- that should come later. i.e., find a solution without thinking, by making the smallest steps. we take the shortest from the rest, and put it at the end of the accumulating ordered list. if its not the longest, put it aside for later. simple(st), I thought. :)

Comment: (*s/shortest/longest) the goal is to have a definition which is self-evidently correct.

Comment: I think before getting into the weeds of selection sort mechanics, it probably pays to mention that you're using a selection sort.

Comment: @dfeuer I'm not even there, I'm inviting the asker to try inventing a wheel here with me. and selection sort is probably much more efficient than this one.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to be lazy. It's incrementally asymptotically optimal, unlike any pure comparison-based sort for this purpose.

```
import Data.Either (partitionEithers)

-- Copied from various packages
partitionWith :: (a -> Either b c) -> [a] -> ([b], [c])
partitionWith f = partitionEithers . map f

sortByLength :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
sortByLength = go . map (\x -> (x, x))
  where
    go :: [(v,[b])] -> [v]
    go [] = []
    go [(v, _)] = v
    go xs = case partitionWith part xs of
      (done, undone) -> done ++ go undone

    part :: (v, [b]) -> Either v (v, [b])
    part (v, []) = Left v
    part (v, _ : bs) = Right (v, bs)
```

Comment: what does "incrementally" mean in this context?

Comment: also, is this really better than `sortOn length`? consider `["1", show (10^n)]`. won't this version take time ~ n^2 instead of `O(1)`?

Comment: @WillNess, I made a mistake. Lemme fix that.

Comment: @WillNess, I fixed it now. The old one wasn't as bad as you suggested, I don't think, but this is what I meant to do. It should take time proportional to the sum of the lengths of the lists, excluding the uninformative tail of the longest one.

Comment: Incrementally means it only does as much work as needed to produce the next element. Not front loaded.

Comment: you have a typo with `go [(v, _)] -> v`, but consider `["1", show (10^n), show (10^n)]`. I don't think this problem can be avoided.

Comment: @WillNess, I produce `"1"` after walking just one cons into each of the other strings. I don't need their lengths.

Comment: yes I got that, and it is nice, but to produce the 2nd elt in the result will take O(n) time.... presumably the built-in `length` is faster that all the machinations your code goes through. :)

Comment: @WillNess, there's no way to avoid (eventually) walking the second-longest list; you can only avoid walking the excess part of the longest. `sortByLength [[], [1], [1..]]`. I imagine you're right about speed in typical cases.

Comment: @WillNess, although being incremental can sometimes be very helpful for real-world performance, so I shouldn't concede that so easily.

Comment: you can have two longest though. or 200. you bring a good point though, `take 2 $ yourExample` won't diverge. counting in unary always helps making arithmetic more logical.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231481/discussion-between-dfeuer-and-will-ness).